# Symfony - FOSUserBundle big objects

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony

When i try to use:

```
$user = $userRepo->find($id)
```

with FOSUserBundle then I receives a large object. Of course i can use my own repo query to find it and return as array, but i want to update this user by:

```
$user->setName('asd');
```

If there is any other way to get a smaller object by find function? Any hydrate or whatever. The reference is not a solution in my case.

Comment: What is the problem with returning the whole object?  How 'large' is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you could use **[Partial Objects](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/partial-objects.html)** to achieve just that:

```
$userId = ...; // you user id
$user = $em
    ->createQuery("SELECT PARTIAL u.{id,name} from AppBundle:User u WHERE u.id = :id")
    ->setParameter('id', $userId)
    ->getSingleResult();

$user->setName("some new name");
$em->flush();
```

I haven't tried running this, but it sounds like it could work...

Comment: Yes this would work, although like the documentation says I would be very careful about using this.  For example, if you wanted to change any other field on the retrieved partial object, it wouldn't be updated on flush.  So if you did `$user->setSomethingElse("blah");` it wouldn't get updated in the database.